# git merge --squash leading to conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a repo that looks like this:

```
           T1  T2
           |   |
master A-B-C-D-E
        \
release  \-R1
```

It consists of a master branch with a lot of development and a number of tag points (here T1, T2).  I also have a release branch.  The purpose for the release branch is to create a line of development which only contains released states of the source code (represented by the tags), *without* master's development history in the logs.

I can create the first commit in the release branch using:

```
git merge --squash T1
git commit -a -m "state T1"
```

but when I go to create the next revision like so

```
git merge --squash T2
```

I get a slew of conflicts.  I think this is because git does not know that the commit A..R1 actually represents A..C so it tries to "reapply" those commits (in some sense, don't know exactly how this is implemented).

Is there a way to merge --squash the commits between T1 and T2?  Or some other way to get the changes from C..E on top of R1?

Comment: You might want to consider using tags instead of squashing commits. Then you can just merge and update your tag instead of your whole branch.

Comment: The release branch is to be pushed to a public server.  So I don't think tags will help me.   Correct me if wrong.

Comment: you can delete the remote tag then re-add it. Tags work great remotely

Comment: I can't say I understand your solution.  What branch do I push to remote that won't also push the history?

Comment: We can chat about this if you wish, but I do not quite understand why you are rewriting the history and squashing, when you could keep history push to a branch and just move a tag around to know where your release is.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, you can assume that a supreme being has mandated it.  (It relates to a company policy.)